# Error on django runserver - OverflowError: getsockaddrarg: port must be 0-65535

Tags: django, sockets, port

I came back to my previously working django project to find the following error after the runserver command:

```
0 errors found
March 20, 2014 - 23:58:52
Django version 1.6.2, using settings 'roja.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:80000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x21cc398>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/pay-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 93, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/pay-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 127, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading)
  File "/home/vagrant/pay-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 167, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "/home/vagrant/pay-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 109, in __init__
    super(WSGIServer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 408, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/home/vagrant/pay-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 113, in server_bind
    super(WSGIServer, self).server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 48, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
OverflowError: getsockaddrarg: port must be 0-65535.
```

Who knows what's going on?. Thanks all.

Comment: This was a (breaking) change in python 2.x. The 2,5 behavior, inherited from the c library, silently truncated port numbers to 16 bits. 2.7 throws an exception for invalid port numbers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run your application on port 80 thousand (80000) where as we only have up to 65 thousand
(65535) ports. Remove one zero and you should be good to go!

Comment: this is kind of funny, i did the same mistake